# Packages are not available for installation

Tags: updates, package-management

Changing some Software Update settings I possibly corrupted something, and now I don't see many packages in the list. For example:

```
alex@u120464:~$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks
[sudo] password for alex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package codeblocks
```

I checked all options in the Software Sources dialog, but packages are still not available. How can I fix this?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.

Additional information.

```
alex@u120464:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for alex: 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease           
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
...
```

It looks like most Ubuntu repositories are not searched, how can I restore default update behaviour?

Edit.

Finally, the problem was solved by copying `/etc/apt/source.list` file from another computer. This is the offending file content:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ precise main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ precise universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ precise-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: did you successfully updated all the lists? try `sudo apt-get update` (also can perform a upgrade `sudo apt-get upgrade`)

Comment: @Web-E: the question is edited.

Comment: Changing Update server doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by copying /etc/apt/sources.list file from another computer.

Comment: did you save the old one for comparing purpose ?

Comment: @martin-mystere - the old one is added to the question. I have no idea what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please, open-up update-manager or Software Sources depending on your distro then add/tick universe repository from the software sources.

Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  "Adding Repositories in Ubuntu"

> GUI-based repository management is normally accomplished via "Software
>   Sources". This interface can be accessed via several methods. For the
>   latest versions of Ubuntu, the easiest way is to go through the
>   "Ubuntu Software Center". Open the software center, then from the Edit
>   menu select "Software Sources". You will have to enter your password
>   to change settings in this window.
>
> For older versions of ubuntu, there are several options:
>
> ```
> Main Menu: System > Administration > Software Sources.
>
> Synaptic : System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager : >> Settings >> Repositories.
>
> Main Menu: Ubuntu Software Center : >> Edit, Software Sources.
> ```

[image: Ubuntu Software Tab]

Comment: Thanks, universe repository is checked. I checked everything possible in the Software Sources dialog, but most packages are still unavailable.